# Bash while do and if with Telegram API

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop, telegram-bot

I am trying to monitor a 24/7 stream.
For this Iam monitoring the networkspeed of my raspberry.

Network Speed in Kbits:

```
(old="$(</sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes)"; while $(sleep 1); do  now=$(</sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes); echo $((($now-$old)/1024)); old=$now; done)
```

The output is in Kbit/s:

```
    216
    384
    288
    360
    336
    360
```

Now I want use Telegram API to trigger if the speed will sink below 100 Kbit/s

Telegram Code:

```
TELEGRAM=$(curl -s -X POST 'https://api.telegram.org/<BOT ID>:<API KEY>/sendMessage?chat_id=<ID>&text="Stream has problems"')
```

For that I need a while do loop and a if condition.

Kind regards,
Goeks1

EDIT////

```
$(old="$(</sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes)"; while $(sleep 1); do  now=$(</sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes); if (( (now-old)/1024 < 1000 )); then $TELEGRAM ; fi echo $((($now-$old)/1024)); old=$now; done)
```

Comment: You could use an arithmetic expression as an "if" condition: `if (( (now-old)/1024 < 100 )); then do_something; fi` -- within `((...))`, most variables to not need to be preceded by `$`

Comment: Great! Ive added it like above. But now I need a loop every 60 seconds and after three matchs (below 100 Kbits) a Telegram message should be send.

Comment: well, you'll want to increment a variable and use the `sleep` command.

Comment: Sorry, I have not much skills in scirpting... What do you mean with increment e.g. TRIGGER=i++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive solve it. The solution is below.

```
#!/bin/bash

OLD="$(</sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes)"
i=1
        while $(sleep 1m); do
NOW=$(</sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes)

if (( (NOW-OLD)/1024 > 100 )) ; then

        remainder=$(( i % 3 ))
        [ "$remainder" -eq 0 ] && curl -s -X POST 'https://api.telegram.org/<BOT ID>:<API KEY>/sendMessage?chat_id=<ID>&text="Stream has problems"'
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
fi
OLD=$NOW
done
```

Comment: Cool, nice script. Just adding that `while $(sleep 1m)` is just `while sleep 1m`.

Comment: Thank you! Could you name me a diffrence with and without parentheses?